# How to include a point of a float in the output?

Tags: python

I am having a string float and I want the output to be an integer without using built in functions.

Problem: How do I include the point in the output?

```
x = '12.34'
new = {str(i):i for i in range(10)}
x = x.split('.')
print(x)

temp1 = list(x[0])
temp2 = list(x[1])
temp = temp1+temp2
print(temp)


length = len(temp)-1
output = 0

for i in temp:
    output += new[i]*10 **length
    length -=1
    
print(output)
```

The output is:
['12', '34']

['1', '2', '3', '4']

1234

Comment: What do you mean by "an integer with a point in it"?

Comment: Can you kindly show your desired output too.

Comment: And why are you avoiding `int()` and `float()` in the first place?

Comment: Did you mean to convert the string representation of a float number into an actual float number using your code? And it got converted into an integer instead?

Comment: Please read [ask], which says in part "After you post, don't run away too fast—leave the question open in your browser for a bit to see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!"

Comment: The expected output should be 12.34. I could have used int and float instead, however, I aim to seek the output without these. So here, we are parsing the string representation of a float into an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have been looking for something like this -- integer division and mod are very helpful for things like this. I split the string at the decimal as you did which I presume should result in a list of two strings of digit chars. To be even safer, you could check both to verify that all characters are digits before casting int(). But, I split these to find the length of the latter (remainder portion). So, if there are two digits after the decimal, we use n = 2 and use 10 ^ 2 to truncate our new_x (I remove the decimal in the string by replacing '.' with ''. We then have new_x: int = 1234). We can then add the parts back such that we have the desired float. Hope this is what you were looking to do :)

```
def func(x):
    x_split = x.split('.')
    assert (len(x_split) == 2)
    n = len(x_split[1])
    new_x = int(x.replace('.', ''))
    assert (type(new_x) is int)
    int_digit = new_x // 10 ** n
    remainder = new_x % 10 ** n
    out = int_digit + (remainder / 10 ** n)
    return out
x = '12.34'
y = '456.98'
z = '921.3242'
print(func(x), type(func(x)))
print(func(y), type(func(y)))
print(func(z), type(func(z)))
```

This code will produce:

```
12.34 <class 'float'>
456.98 <class 'float'>
921.3242 <class 'float'>
```